# c# : regular expression for large string

Tags: c#, regex

i need to create a regular expression that can match the following patterns. I am reading a large file and needs to grab the strings that matches the pattern. Basically any string between `AND++(*)`

```
AND++("adventure"), 

AND++("Regular"+AND+"Show"), 

AND++("any"+AND+"given"+AND+"sunday") , 

AND++("the"+AND+"greatest"+AND+"story"+AND+"ever"+AND+"told")
```

Comment: What have you tried sir? This is not a homework service for people who dont want to learn regex. Speaking of, it is very straight forward. You should try and pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<=AND\+\+\().*?(?=\))`

will capture everything contained in the quotations, provided the `AND++(` is before, and `)` is after.

`(?<=AND\+\+\()` is the positive look-behind

`(?=\))` is the positive look-ahead

**EDIT**

For Each Match just do:

`match = match.Replace("\"","").Replace("+AND+"," ");`

Comment: Thanks Jonsey for quick solution. I need to treat anything  in * AND++(*) as one string. So for instance "any given sunday" is a string. The plan is to find all the matches and process them further.

Comment: Do you mean you want `"any"+AND+"given"+AND+"sunday"` to eventually be `"any given sunday"`?

Comment: That's exactly i am doing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: var resultList = new StringCollection();

   while (matchResult.Success)
   {
    var repl1 = matchResult.Value.Replace("+AND+", " ").Replace("\"", "");

    resultList.Add(repl1);

    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
   }